# How to make sure that file already moved completely?

Tags: file, delphi

I created a service application. I am moving a file to a folder, then using FileExist to check if the file already exist in the folder then I will do update the file existent in the database table.

The problem is sometime for big file, file still moving but file already exist (if I test using FileExists function, I update the status in database but suddently the pc off (electrical problem or something).

So the status in database is "File found", but in the real location file not there (because file was still on moving but suddently PC was off).

I was simulated with moving big file to a folder and then while this file moving, I check it with FileExists, and the result is True.

Is it a function in delphi that to make sure the file already completely moved ?

Comment: Instead of looking to see if the file exists in the destination directory, you should be looking for the file no longer existing in the source directory. Once the move is complete, the file is deleted from the source.

Comment: Another option is to try and open the target file in Write mode (with Deny All share mode). As long as the copying is going on, you are unable to do so. As soon as you're able to, the file has finished copying (but may still only be in the disk cache, unless you disable this in your FileCopy call).

Comment: Call MoveFileEx passing the MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH flag

Comment: When you say you are moving file to a folder what approach are you using. If you are copying file to a new location then you do need o wait for file copy procedure to be finished. Larger the file longer it takes. But if you are using `MoveFile` or `MoveFileEx` then the operation should be done almost instantly since only information in file allocation table needs to be updated. That is unless the destination folder is on a different drive. In that case the file copy operation is done automatically and could take some time in case of larger file.

Comment: Also add MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED to allow for cross-volume moving. In my case I also add MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING, but that's because it is a RSYNC like backup service.